# How to correctly recreate sklearn (python) logistic regression predict_proba outcome for a binary classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have tried to recreate the outcome from sklearn's logistic regression predict_proba using the logistic/sigmoid function. However, I end up slightly off with my result. I am only looking at a binary  classification (yes/no) and not multiclass.

After fitting the model I get the following weights (where the first weight is the Intercept):

```
 print np.transpose(model.coef_)
>>>
[[-0.19727816]
 [ 0.53109229]
 [-1.31937397]
 [-0.98187463]
 [-0.3479746 ]
 [-0.54423188]
 [ 0.36497145]
 [-0.15778131]
 [-0.21998587]
 [-0.35944243]]
```

If I then use predict_proba on a test case I get the following outcome (again, the first "1"  in the test sample represents the Intercept):

```
test_sample = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
print model.predict_proba(test_sample)    
>>>
[[ 0.9334748  0.0665252]]
```

However, when I then try to recreate this outcome using the logistic function I get a slightly different result:

```
new_profile = test_sample*model.coef_
print np.transpose(new_profile)
>>>
[[-0.19727816]
 [ 0.        ]
 [-1.31937397]
 [-0.        ]
 [-0.3479746 ]
 [-0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [-0.        ]
 [-0.21998587]
 [-0.35944243]]

np_sum = (new_profile).sum()
score = 1/(1+np.exp(-np_sum))
print score
>>>
0.0798743821296
```

I get ~8% instead of 6,6%, most likely because I am missing a step in my calculations.
I know that in the multiclass example you should do normalization:

```
score /= score.sum(axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
```

However, this does not work as I am just using a binary classification with 1 outcome!?

Can anyone spot what step am I missing in order to correctly calculate the same outcome as the predict_proba?

Comment: I suggest looking through the `LinearClassifierMixin` class [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/base.py)

Comment: I think you just pointed me to the right place! I ended up with a dead end looking for that `_predict_proba_lr` which is part of the `LinearClassifierMixin`! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you added   new_profile = test_sample*model.coef_ + self.intercept_